# Cabal failed to install package because it needs cabal

Tags: haskell, package, cabal

When I try to install directory package I get following error:

```
$ cabal install directory
Resolving dependencies...
Failed to install directory-1.2.2.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
directory-1.2.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (The package requires Cabal library version -any && >=1.10 but no
suitable version is installed.)
```

My cabal version is:

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

I tried to execute cabal install Cabal but it depens on directory so it also fails. What is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: I think this would have to be related to your other question: Cabal, like GHC, is fundamentally confused on where the package lives. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Try `cabal install cabal cabal-install`. from https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html

Answer (score 2):

Cabal (a library) and cabal-install (an executable) are not the same thing. You need to upgrade your cabal-install:

```
cabal install cabal cabal-install
```

Your version (1.16) is ancient.